# DRUPAL You are not authorized to access this page after clearing cookies

Tags: cookies, drupal, authentication, drupal-7

I was logged as a siteadmin on my local page, after clearing cookies I cannot login again on this same login and password. I tried to upload the backup of the database when i can login, but it not helped, i clear all the cache.
Did someone had a such problem? How to resolve it?
Thanks,
Vergili

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

1. Go in PhpAdmin and select the database of your drupal website
2. Scroll down and Go to record users, admin user is always the first user id:1
3. Make EDIT the first user (admin user) and change field email with your email.
4. After email changed, go to your website and try to do "forgot password" on your loggin page, you will receive a email restore password in your email inserted in your database.

This can be a way to login again like admin.

Comment: this not working, i log with right login and password but it tells me You are not authorized to access this page

Comment: what is the page where you can not access? so issue is that you can not login like admin or error access to a specific page?

Comment: I cannot login as an admin, but I didn't changed the pass and user is id:1, it works fine before clearing the cookies, now I cannot login

Comment: this is strange, cookies not give changes on database of drupal, did you try to restore password?

Comment: Something strange, on the local server I cannot log, but when I put the project on the production server I can login with the same login and password as on the local... someone know what's going on?

Comment: check the connection of database, if it work on server must work also in your local server, check local connection, server: root; database: younameDB ; password: yourpasswordDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Drush installed you can navigate to your sites root directory in the console and type `drush uli` It will give you a one time login.

it will look like:

```
http://default/user/reset/1/1464702672/4-mLpgYQqVblYxY3xPq4hY6yF9K1vCvsvfOHgGNyhWg/login
```

Replace 'default' with your domain.